# PUT request from Flash SWF

Tags: flash, swfobject

I'm a newbie in Flash and I need to make a PUT request from an SWF file on a web page. I made the follwing PoC:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.net.*;

    public class Test extends Sprite {
        public function Test() {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://test-host.com");
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.PUT;
            request.data = "some-data";
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.load(request);
        }
    }
}
```

But being executed in a browser this code fails with the error:

```
ArgumentError: Error #2008: Parameter method must be one of the accepted values.
 at flash.net::URLRequest/setMethod()
 at flash.net::URLRequest/set method()
 at Test()
```

At the same time [Adobe documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestMethod.html) states that PUT method is supported. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this?

Comment: I carried out several experiments and it turned out that it's not supported by Flash for browsers.